# "Less than" on $\mathbb{R}$ is an order relation?

Tags: real-analysis, relations

Sorry for the seemingly dumb question, but I really don't understand how $<$ is an order relation on $\mathbb{R}$, if $x < x$ is not satisfied for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: $<$ is not an order relation, but $\leq$ is.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe 
That's what I don't understand. There is an example in the Munkres Topology book that says it is an order relation.

Comment: See [Total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order).  The punchline in the end is that authors might sometimes use different words than other authors, but they will generally define what they mean.  Be aware of the distinction between what we consider "*strict*" orders which are irreflexive and "*non-strict*" orders which are reflexive.  The less than relation is indeed the quintessential example of a strict total order.

Answer (score 2):

You have two notions:

- *[(non-strict) (partial) order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Non-strict_partial_order)* (reflexive, antisymmetric, transitive) and
- *[strict (partial) order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_partial_order)* (irreflexive, transitive).

$\le$ is the example of the former, $\lt$ of the latter.

Those two notions are tightly coupled: if $\lt$ is a strict order, you make a (non-strict) partial order $\le$ by saying

$$x\le y\overset{\text{def}}{\iff}(x\lt y) \lor (x=y)$$

If $\le$ is a (non-strict) partial order, you make a strict order $\lt$ by saying

$$x\lt y\overset{\text{def}}{\iff}(x\le y) \land\lnot(x=y)$$

In addition, the mappings of the strict order $\lt$ to the partial order $\le$ and back are bijections, they put those two kinds of relations into $1-1$ correspondence with each other. Thus, we can always just say "order" and mention one of those relations (e.g. the strict order one), knowing that we can reconstruct the unique other relation (e.g. the non-strict one) using the aforementioned correspondence.

Comment: It is true that you can translate between these two notions but the difference between them really does matter, for example when defining what an ordered ring is. The axiom that if $x \ge 0, y \ge 0$ then $xy \ge 0$ is strictly weaker than the axiom that if $x > 0, y > 0$ then $xy > 0$; the latter axiom forces the ring to be an integral domain but the former axiom doesn't.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Agreed! The fact that we can mentally switch from one of those relations to the other and back does not absolve us from responsibility to know at each moment which one we are actually dealing with.